BP neural network for digit recognition
In the process of using MATLAB for image digit recognition, due to task requirements, I needed to use a BP neural network. I generated 500 images of digits from 0 to 9 and set up a two-layer neural network, but the prediction results have not reached 90%. I'm a beginner in machine learning, and I would greatly appreciate any guidance.
two-layer result

clc; clear;

% Load training data
trainData = imageDatastore('D:\Matlab_Project\CourseProject\BP\Datasets\train', ...
    'IncludeSubfolders', true, ...
    'FileExtensions', '.jpg', ...
    'LabelSource', 'foldernames'); % Change extension to .jpg
testData = imageDatastore('Datasets/test', 'LabelSource', 'foldernames', 'FileExtensions', '.png');

imageSize = [32, 32];
numImages = numel(trainData.Files);

% Define image augmentation parameters
imageAugmenter = imageDataAugmenter('RandRotation', [-20, 20], 'RandXReflection', true);

% Create augmented image data store
augmentedTrainData = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize, trainData, 'DataAugmentation', imageAugmenter);

% Read augmented images
trainFeatures = zeros(numImages, prod(imageSize));

for i = 1:numImages
    img = readByIndex(augmentedTrainData, i); % Read data by index
    trainImg = cell2mat(img{1, 1}); % Get image data
    Img = double(trainImg); % Convert to grayscale and normalize to [0, 1]
    train_img = (Img - min(Img(:))) / (max(Img(:)) - min(Img(:))); % Normalize to [0, 1]
    trainFeatures(i, :) = train_img(:)'; % Flatten normalized image and store
end

% Initialize labels
trainLabels = zeros(numImages, 1);
for i = 1:numImages
    % Get file path and extract label
    name = trainData.Labels(i);
    trainLabels(i) = double(name)-1;  % Convert label to number and subtract 1 to match MATLAB indexing
end

% Generate a random permutation index
randomIdx = randperm(numImages);

% Shuffle training data and labels according to random index
shuffledFeatures = trainFeatures(randomIdx, :);
shuffledLabels = trainLabels(randomIdx, :);

% Split training and validation sets
trainRatio = 0.8;
numTrainImages = round(numImages * trainRatio);

trainFeatures = shuffledFeatures(1:numTrainImages, :);
trainLabels = shuffledLabels(1:numTrainImages, :); % Assuming valFeatures is validation set features
valFeatures = shuffledFeatures(numTrainImages+1:end, :); % Validation set features
valLabels = shuffledLabels(numTrainImages+1:end, :);

% Initialize the neural network
inputLayer = size(trainFeatures, 2);
hiddenLayer1Size = 9;  % First hidden layer node count
hiddenLayer2Size = 1;  % Second hidden layer node count
OutputLayerSize = 10;  % Corresponding to 10 labels for 0~9

% Initialize feedforward weights and biases
W1 = randn(hiddenLayer1Size, inputLayer) * sqrt(2 / inputLayer); % He initialization
b1 = zeros(hiddenLayer1Size, 1);  % Hidden layer bias initialized to 0

W2 = randn(hiddenLayer2Size, hiddenLayer1Size) * sqrt(2 / hiddenLayer1Size); % He initialization
b2 = zeros(hiddenLayer2Size, 1);  % Second hidden layer bias initialized to 0

W3 = randn(OutputLayerSize, hiddenLayer2Size) * sqrt(2 / hiddenLayer2Size); % He initialization
b3 = zeros(OutputLayerSize, 1);   % Output layer bias initialized to 0

batchSize = 20; % Number of samples for batch learning
valPredictions = zeros(size(valLabels)); % Initialize validation set predictions
numValBatches = ceil(size(valFeatures, 1) / batchSize); % Calculate validation set batch count
totalValLoss = 0;

for batch = 1:numValBatches
    % Calculate indices for the current batch
    startIdx = (batch - 1) * batchSize + 1;
    endIdx = min(batch * batchSize, size(valFeatures, 1));
    
    % Get features for the current batch
    X_val_batch = valFeatures(startIdx:endIdx, :)'; % Input, dimensions [inputSize, batchSize]
    
    % Forward propagation
    Z1_val = W1 * X_val_batch + b1; % Weighted input for first hidden layer
    A1_val = activation(Z1_val, "sigmoid"); % Activation output for first hidden layer
    Z2_val = W2 * A1_val + b2; % Weighted input for second hidden layer
    A2_val = activation(Z2_val, "sigmoid"); % Activation output for second hidden layer
    Z3_val = W3 * A2_val + b3; % Weighted input for output layer
    A3_val = softmax(Z3_val); % Activation output for output layer
    
    % Calculate cross-entropy loss
    idx = sub2ind(size(A3_val), valLabels(startIdx:endIdx)' + 1, 1:size(A3_val, 2));
    batchLoss = -mean(log(A3_val(idx))); % Cross-entropy loss calculation
    
    % Accumulate batch loss into total loss
    totalValLoss = totalValLoss + batchLoss;
end

% Calculate average validation loss
averageValLoss = totalValLoss / numValBatches;
disp(['Initial Validation Loss: ', num2str(averageValLoss)]);

% Backpropagation
learningRate = 0.0001;
epochNum = 1000;
bestValLoss = inf;
numTrainImages = size(trainLabels,1);
batchSize = 20;
trainLosses = zeros(epochNum, 1); % Store training loss for each epoch
valLosses = zeros(epochNum, 1);    % Store validation loss for each epoch
numBatches = ceil(numTrainImages / batchSize);
numBatches = size(numBatches,1);

lambda = 0.019;  % Regularization strength

% Adam optimizer parameters
alpha = 0.001;  % Initial learning rate
beta1 = 0.9;
beta2 = 0.999;
epsilon = 1e-8;

% Initialize parameters
mW1 = zeros(size(W1)); vW1 = zeros(size(W1));
mb1 = zeros(size(b1)); vb1 = zeros(size(b1));
mW2 = zeros(size(W2)); vW2 = zeros(size(W2));
mb2 = zeros(size(b2)); vb2 = zeros(size(b2));
mW3 = zeros(size(W3)); vW3 = zeros(size(W3));
mb3 = zeros(size(b3)); vb3 = zeros(size(b3));

% Backpropagation

for epoch = 1:epochNum
    epochLoss = 0;
    
    for batch = 1:numBatches
        % Calculate the index for the current batch
        startIdx = (batch - 1) * batchSize + 1;
        endIdx = min(batch * batchSize, numTrainImages);
        
        % Get the data for the current batch
        X_batch = trainFeatures(startIdx:endIdx, :)';  % Input
        Y_batch = trainLabels(startIdx:endIdx)';    % Labels
        
        % Forward propagation
        Z1 = W1 * X_batch + b1;          % Weighted input for the first hidden layer
        A1 = activation(Z1, "sigmoid");  % Activation output for the first hidden layer
        Z2 = W2 * A1 + b2;               % Weighted input for the second hidden layer
        A2 = activation(Z2, "sigmoid");  % Activation output for the second hidden layer
        Z3 = W3 * A2 + b3;               % Weighted input for the output layer
        A3 = softmax(Z3);                % Activation output for the output layer
        
        % Calculate error
        idx = sub2ind(size(A3), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A3, 2));
        epsilon = 1e-10;
        error = -mean(log(A3(idx) + epsilon));  % Use average cross-entropy
        epochLoss = epochLoss + error;
        
        % Backpropagation
        delta3 = A3;  % Initialize delta3 as the probabilities from A3
        delta3(sub2ind(size(A3), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A3, 2))) = delta3(sub2ind(size(A3), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A3, 2))) - 1;
        delta2 = (W3' * delta3) .* diff_activation(A2, "sigmoid");  % Error term for the second hidden layer
        delta1 = (W2' * delta2) .* diff_activation(A1, "sigmoid");  % Error term for the first hidden layer
        
        % Calculate gradients
        gradW3 = delta3 * A2' / size(A3, 2) + lambda * W3; % Include L2 regularization
        gradb3 = mean(delta3, 2);
        gradW2 = delta2 * A1' / size(A3, 2) + lambda * W2; % Include L2 regularization
        gradb2 = mean(delta2, 2);
        gradW1 = delta1 * X_batch' / size(A3, 2) + lambda * W1; % Include L2 regularization
        gradb1 = mean(delta1, 2);
        
        % Update first moment estimates
        mW1 = beta1 * mW1 + (1 - beta1) * gradW1;
        mb1 = beta1 * mb1 + (1 - beta1) * gradb1;
        mW2 = beta1 * mW2 + (1 - beta1) * gradW2;
        mb2 = beta1 * mb2 + (1 - beta1) * gradb2;
        mW3 = beta1 * mW3 + (1 - beta1) * gradW3;
        mb3 = beta1 * mb3 + (1 - beta1) * gradb3;
        
        % Update second moment estimates
        vW1 = beta2 * vW1 + (1 - beta2) * (gradW1 .^ 2);
        vb1 = beta2 * vb1 + (1 - beta2) * (gradb1 .^ 2);
        vW2 = beta2 * vW2 + (1 - beta2) * (gradW2 .^ 2);
        vb2 = beta2 * vb2 + (1 - beta2) * (gradb2 .^ 2);
        vW3 = beta2 * vW3 + (1 - beta2) * (gradW3 .^ 2);
        vb3 = beta2 * vb3 + (1 - beta2) * (gradb3 .^ 2);
        
        % Compute bias-corrected estimates
        mW1_hat = mW1 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mb1_hat = mb1 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mW2_hat = mW2 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mb2_hat = mb2 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mW3_hat = mW3 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mb3_hat = mb3 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        vW1_hat = vW1 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vb1_hat = vb1 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vW2_hat = vW2 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vb2_hat = vb2 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vW3_hat = vW3 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vb3_hat = vb3 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        
        % Update weights and biases
        W1 = W1 - alpha * mW1_hat ./ (sqrt(vW1_hat) + epsilon);
        b1 = b1 - alpha * mb1_hat ./ (sqrt(vb1_hat) + epsilon);
        W2 = W2 - alpha * mW2_hat ./ (sqrt(vW2_hat) + epsilon);
        b2 = b2 - alpha * mb2_hat ./ (sqrt(vb2_hat) + epsilon);
        W3 = W3 - alpha * mW3_hat ./ (sqrt(vW3_hat) + epsilon);
        b3 = b3 - alpha * mb3_hat ./ (sqrt(vb3_hat) + epsilon);
    end
    
    % Calculate training loss, including L2 regularization
    trainLosses(epoch) = (epochLoss / numBatches) + (lambda / 2) * (norm(W1, 'fro')^2 + norm(W2, 'fro')^2 + norm(W3, 'fro')^2);
    
    % Validation loss calculation (without Dropout)
    valPredictions = zeros(size(valLabels));
    
    % Validation loss calculation (without loops)
    Z1_val = W1 * valFeatures' + b1;
    A1_val = activation(Z1_val, "sigmoid");
    Z2_val = W2 * A1_val + b2;
    A2_val = activation(Z2_val, "sigmoid");
    Z3_val = W3 * A2_val + b3;
    A3_val = softmax(Z3_val);
    
    % Select the actual class probabilities for each sample as the basis for validation loss calculation
    valIdx = sub2ind(size(A3_val), valLabels' + 1, 1:size(A3_val, 2));
    valLoss = -mean(log(A3_val(valIdx) + epsilon));  % Calculate average cross-entropy loss
    valLoss = valLoss + (lambda / 2) * (norm(W1, 'fro')^2 + norm(W2, 'fro')^2 + norm(W3, 'fro')^2);  % Include regularization in validation loss
    valLosses(epoch) = valLoss;
    
    % Predict classes
    [~, predictedLabels] = max(A3_val, [], 1); 
    valPredictions = predictedLabels - 1; % Subtract 1 from the index to match label range 0-9
    
    disp(['Epoch: ' num2str(epoch) ', Training Error: ' num2str(epochLoss / numBatches) ', Validation Loss: ' num2str(valLoss)]);
end



% Plot training loss and validation loss curves
figure;
hold on;
plot(trainLosses(1:epoch), 'LineWidth', 1.5);
plot(valLosses(1:epoch), 'LineWidth', 1.5);
xlabel('Epoch');
ylabel('Loss');
title('Training and Validation Loss');
legend('Training Loss', 'Validation Loss');
grid on;
hold off;

% Predictions for the test set (without Dropout)
%%% Simple test
testFeatures = zeros(numel(testData.Files), prod(imageSize));
for i = 1:numel(testData.Files)
    img = imread(testData.Files{i}); % Use the test dataset files
    img = imresize(rgb2gray(im2double(img)), imageSize); % Normalize and resize
    img = (img - mean(img(:))) / std(img(:)); % Standardize to zero mean and unit variance
    testFeatures(i, :) = img(:)'; % Flatten the image and store it
end
testPredictions = zeros(size(testFeatures, 1), OutputLayerSize);
for j = 1:size(testFeatures, 1)
    X_test = testFeatures(j, :)';  % Get the feature vector for a single test sample
    
    % Forward propagation (without Dropout)
    Z1_test = W1 * X_test + b1;
    A1_test = activation(Z1_test, "sigmoid");
    Z2_test = W2 * A1_test + b2;
    A2_test = activation(Z2_test, "sigmoid");  % Activation output for the second hidden layer
    Z3_test = W3 * A2_test + b3;
    A3_test = softmax(Z3_test);
    testPredictions(j, :) = A3_test; % Store the output probabilities
end

% Get the predicted labels based on the test predictions
[~, finalPredictions] = max(testPredictions, [], 2);
finalPredictions = finalPredictions - 1; % Convert to label format


function y = activation(x, method)
    %% Options: sigmoid, tanh, relu, softmax
    if strcmp(method, "sigmoid")
        y = logsig(x);  % Sigmoid activation function
    elseif strcmp(method, "tanh")
        y = tanh(x);    % Tanh activation function
    elseif strcmp(method, "relu")
        y = max(0, x);  % ReLU activation function
    elseif strcmp(method, "softmax")
        % expX = exp(x - max(x)); % Adjustment for numerical stability
        % y = expX / sum(expX);   % Softmax activation function
        y = softmax(x);
    else
        error('Unsupported activation method. Choose from: sigmoid, tanh, relu, softmax.');
    end
end

function y = diff_activation(x, method)
    % Gradient of activation functions: sigmoid, tanh, relu, softmax
    if strcmp(method, "sigmoid")
        y = (x) .* (1 - x);  % Derivative of sigmoid
    elseif strcmp(method, "tanh")
        y = 1 - (x).^2;      % Derivative of tanh
    elseif strcmp(method, "relu")
        y = x > 0;           % Derivative of ReLU: 1 for parts greater than 0, 0 otherwise
    elseif strcmp(method, "softmax")
        % Derivative of softmax: diagonal part
        s = exp(x) ./ sum(exp(x));
        y = diag(s) - (s * s');
    else
        error('Unsupported activation method. Choose from: sigmoid, tanh, relu, softmax.');
    end
end

I also tried using a single-layer neural network, but the results were unsatisfactory.
single-layer result
clc; clear;

% Load training data
trainData = imageDatastore('D:\Matlab_Project\CourseProject\BP\Datasets\train', ...
    'IncludeSubfolders', true, ...
    'FileExtensions', '.jpg', ...
    'LabelSource', 'foldernames'); % Change the extension to .jpg

testData = imageDatastore('Datasets/test', ...
    'IncludeSubfolders', true, ...
    'FileExtensions', '.png', ...
    'LabelSource', 'foldernames'); % Test data remains unchanged

imageSize = [32, 32];
numImages = numel(trainData.Files);

% Define image augmentation parameters
imageAugmenter = imageDataAugmenter('RandRotation', [-20, 20], 'RandXReflection', true);

% Create augmented image data storage
augmentedTrainData = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize, trainData, 'DataAugmentation', imageAugmenter);

% Read augmented images
trainFeatures = zeros(numImages, prod(imageSize));

for i = 1:numImages
    img = readByIndex(augmentedTrainData, i); % Use readByIndex to read data by index
    trainImg = cell2mat(img{1, 1}); % Retrieve image data
    Img = double(trainImg); % Convert to grayscale and normalize to [0, 1]
    train_img = (Img - min(Img(:))) / (max(Img(:)) - min(Img(:))); % Normalize to [0, 1]
    trainFeatures(i, :) = train_img(:)'; % Flatten and store the normalized image
end

% Initialize labels
trainLabels = zeros(numImages, 1);  
for i = 1:numImages
    % Retrieve file path and extract label
    name = trainData.Labels(i);
    trainLabels(i) = double(name)-1;  % Convert label to a number and subtract 1 to fit MATLAB indexing
end 

% Generate a random shuffle index
randomIdx = randperm(numImages);

% Shuffle training data and labels according to the random index
shuffledFeatures = trainFeatures(randomIdx, :);
shuffledLabels = trainLabels(randomIdx, :);

% Split training and validation sets
trainRatio = 0.8;  
numTrainImages = round(numImages * trainRatio);

trainFeatures = shuffledFeatures(1:numTrainImages, :);
trainLabels = shuffledLabels(1:numTrainImages, :); % Assume valFeatures are validation set features
valFeatures = shuffledFeatures(numTrainImages+1:end, :); % Validation set features
valLabels = shuffledLabels(numTrainImages+1:end, :);

% Initialize neural network
inputLayer = size(trainFeatures, 2);
hiddenLayerSize = 9;
OutputLayerSize = 10;   % Corresponds to 10 labels (0~9)

% Forward feed
W1 = randn(hiddenLayerSize, inputLayer) * sqrt(2 / inputLayer); % He initialization
W2 = randn(OutputLayerSize, hiddenLayerSize) * sqrt(2 / hiddenLayerSize); % He initialization
b1 = zeros(hiddenLayerSize, 1);  % Initialize hidden layer bias to 0
b2 = zeros(OutputLayerSize, 1);  % Initialize output layer bias to 0

batchSize = 50; % Number of samples per batch for batch learning
valPredictions = zeros(size(valLabels)); % Initialize validation predictions
numValBatches = ceil(size(valFeatures, 1) / batchSize); % Calculate validation batches

totalValLoss = 0;
for batch = 1:numValBatches
    % Calculate current batch index
    startIdx = (batch - 1) * batchSize + 1;
    endIdx = min(batch * batchSize, size(valFeatures, 1));
    
    % Get current batch features
    X_val_batch = valFeatures(startIdx:endIdx, :)'; % Input, dimensions [inputSize, batchSize]
    
    % Forward propagation
    Z1_val = W1 * X_val_batch + b1; % Weighted input for hidden layer
    A1_val = activation(Z1_val, "sigmoid"); % Hidden layer activation output
    Z2_val = W2 * A1_val + b2; % Weighted input for output layer
    
    % Apply softmax activation function
    A2_val = softmax(Z2_val);
    
    % Calculate cross-entropy loss
    idx = sub2ind(size(A2_val), valLabels(startIdx:endIdx)' + 1, 1:size(A2_val, 2));
    batchLoss = -mean(log(A2_val(idx))); % Cross-entropy loss calculation
    
    % Accumulate batch loss to total loss
    totalValLoss = totalValLoss + batchLoss; 
end

% Calculate average validation loss
averageValLoss = totalValLoss / numValBatches;
disp(['Initial Validation Loss: ', num2str(averageValLoss)]);

% Backpropagation
learningRate = 0.01;
epochNum = 1000;
bestValLoss = inf;
numTrainImages = size(trainLabels, 1);
batchSize = 40;
trainLosses = zeros(epochNum, 1); % Store training loss for each epoch
valLosses = zeros(epochNum, 1);   % Store validation loss for each epoch
numBatches = ceil(numTrainImages / batchSize);

lambda = 0.005;  % Regularization strength

% Adam optimizer parameters
alpha = 0.001;  % Initial learning rate
beta1 = 0.9;
beta2 = 0.999;
epsilon = 1e-8;

% Initialize parameters
mW1 = zeros(size(W1)); vW1 = zeros(size(W1));
mb1 = zeros(size(b1)); vb1 = zeros(size(b1));
mW2 = zeros(size(W2)); vW2 = zeros(size(W2));
mb2 = zeros(size(b2)); vb2 = zeros(size(b2));

for epoch = 1:epochNum
    epochLoss = 0;
    
    for batch = 1:numBatches
        % Calculate current batch index
        startIdx = (batch - 1) * batchSize + 1;
        endIdx = min(batch * batchSize, numTrainImages);
        
        % Get current batch data
        X_batch = trainFeatures(startIdx:endIdx, :)';  % Input
        Y_batch = trainLabels(startIdx:endIdx)';       % Label
        
        % Forward propagation
        Z1 = W1 * X_batch + b1;          % Weighted input for hidden layer
        A1 = activation(Z1, "sigmoid");  % Hidden layer activation output
        Z2 = W2 * A1 + b2;               % Weighted input for output layer
        A2 = softmax(Z2);                % Output layer activation output
        
        % Compute error
        idx = sub2ind(size(A2), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A2, 2));
        error = -mean(log(A2(idx) + epsilon));  % Use mean cross-entropy
        epochLoss = epochLoss + error;
        
        % Backpropagation
        delta2 = A2;  % Initialize delta2 as probabilities in A2
        delta2(sub2ind(size(A2), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A2, 2))) = delta2(sub2ind(size(A2), Y_batch + 1, 1:size(A2, 2))) - 1;
        delta1 = (W2' * delta2) .* diff_activation(A1, "sigmoid");  % Hidden layer error term
        
        % Calculate gradients
        gradW2 = delta2 * A1' / size(A2, 2) + lambda * W2; % Include L2 regularization
        gradb2 = mean(delta2, 2);
        gradW1 = delta1 * X_batch' / size(A2, 2) + lambda * W1; % Include L2 regularization
        gradb1 = mean(delta1, 2);
        
        % Update first moment estimates
        mW1 = beta1 * mW1 + (1 - beta1) * gradW1;
        mb1 = beta1 * mb1 + (1 - beta1) * gradb1;
        mW2 = beta1 * mW2 + (1 - beta1) * gradW2;
        mb2 = beta1 * mb2 + (1 - beta1) * gradb2;
        
        % Update second moment estimates
        vW1 = beta2 * vW1 + (1 - beta2) * (gradW1 .^ 2);
        vb1 = beta2 * vb1 + (1 - beta2) * (gradb1 .^ 2);
        vW2 = beta2 * vW2 + (1 - beta2) * (gradW2 .^ 2);
        vb2 = beta2 * vb2 + (1 - beta2) * (gradb2 .^ 2);
        
        % Calculate bias-corrected estimates
        mW1_hat = mW1 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mb1_hat = mb1 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mW2_hat = mW2 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        mb2_hat = mb2 / (1 - beta1^epoch);
        vW1_hat = vW1 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vb1_hat = vb1 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vW2_hat = vW2 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        vb2_hat = vb2 / (1 - beta2^epoch);
        
        % Update weights and biases
        W1 = W1 - alpha * mW1_hat ./ (sqrt(vW1_hat) + epsilon);
        b1 = b1 - alpha * mb1_hat ./ (sqrt(vb1_hat) + epsilon);
        W2 = W2 - alpha * mW2_hat ./ (sqrt(vW2_hat) + epsilon);
        b2 = b2 - alpha * mb2_hat ./ (sqrt(vb2_hat) + epsilon);
    end
    
    % Store training loss for current epoch
    trainLosses(epoch) = epochLoss / numTrainImages;
    
    % Validate on validation set
    valPredictions = zeros(size(valLabels));
    numValBatches = ceil(size(valFeatures, 1) / batchSize);
        % Reset total validation loss for current epoch
    totalValLoss = 0;

    for batch = 1:numValBatches
        % Calculate current batch index
        startIdx = (batch - 1) * batchSize + 1;
        endIdx = min(batch * batchSize, size(valFeatures, 1));

        % Get current batch features
        X_val_batch = valFeatures(startIdx:endIdx, :)';

        % Forward propagation on validation set
        Z1_val = W1 * X_val_batch + b1;  % Weighted input for hidden layer
        A1_val = activation(Z1_val, "sigmoid");  % Hidden layer activation output
        Z2_val = W2 * A1_val + b2;  % Weighted input for output layer

        % Apply softmax activation for output layer
        A2_val = softmax(Z2_val);

        % Calculate cross-entropy loss for the batch
        idx = sub2ind(size(A2_val), valLabels(startIdx:endIdx)' + 1, 1:size(A2_val, 2));
        batchLoss = -mean(log(A2_val(idx) + epsilon));
        
        % Accumulate batch loss into total validation loss
        totalValLoss = totalValLoss + batchLoss;
    end

    % Calculate average validation loss for the epoch
    averageValLoss = totalValLoss / numValBatches;
    valLosses(epoch) = averageValLoss;

    % Display loss information
    disp(['Epoch ', num2str(epoch), ' - Training Loss: ', num2str(trainLosses(epoch)), ...
          ' - Validation Loss: ', num2str(averageValLoss)]);

    % Early stopping: save model if validation loss improves
    if averageValLoss < bestValLoss
        bestValLoss = averageValLoss;
        bestW1 = W1;
        bestb1 = b1;
        bestW2 = W2;
        bestb2 = b2;
        patienceCounter = 0;  % Reset patience counter if validation improves
    else
        patienceCounter = patienceCounter + 1;
        if patienceCounter >= patience
            disp('Early stopping triggered.');
            break;
        end
    end
end

% Plot training and validation loss over epochs
figure;
plot(1:epoch, trainLosses(1:epoch), '-o', 'DisplayName', 'Training Loss');
hold on;
plot(1:epoch, valLosses(1:epoch), '-x', 'DisplayName', 'Validation Loss');
xlabel('Epoch');
ylabel('Loss');
legend;
title('Training and Validation Loss');
grid on;

% Load best model weights
W1 = bestW1;
b1 = bestb1;
W2 = bestW2;
b2 = bestb2;

disp('Training completed. Best validation loss: ');
disp(bestValLoss);




I noticed an issue: if the size of the training set images differs significantly from the test set images, reducing the test images to match the training size may cause feature loss. Will this have a significant impact?
